# Why is where clause only returning one result when I know theirs multiple hits?

Tags: java, sql-server, dateadd

Only returns one record when i know their are records in the db that meet criteria for 3 of the date portions. Could it be the chaining of the and or's ? The one record that is returned falls into it's proper range which made me place blame on the db not having but one record that met criteria but after checking db i should have 3 records in result set.

```
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet result_set = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String terminated = "SELECT distinct b.new_TagID, c.AccountId, c.Name, a.OwnerId, b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate,"
                + " a.JobTitle, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.EMailAddress1, a.new_Support_RenewalContact, a.new_Supported"
                + "RenevalContact, d.YomiFullName, d.InternalEMailAddress,"
                + " (SELECT InternalEMailAddress from dbo.SystemUserBase where SystemUserId=e.new_VPId) new_VPId,"
                + " (SELECT InternalEMailAddress from dbo.SystemUserBase where SystemUserId=e.new_RVPId) new_RVPId,"
                + "b.new_RenewalOpptyIDyr2,b.new_RenewalOpptyIDyr3,b.new_RenewalOpptyIDyr4,b.new_RenewalOpptyIDyr5, "
                + " Case when b.new_LevelofSupport = 100000000 then 'Platinum' "
                +        "when b.new_LevelofSupport = 100000001 then 'Standard' "
                +        "when b.new_LevelofSupport = 100000002 then 'NONE' "
                +        "when b.new_LevelofSupport = 100000003 then 'Standard with AR' end as LeveloFSupport "
                + "FROM dbo.contact as a, dbo.new_assetExtensionBase as b, dbo.AccountBase as c, dbo.SystemUserBase as d, dbo.SystemUserExtensionBase as e "
                + "WHERE b.new_account=a.AccountId AND a.AccountId=c.AccountId AND c.OwnerId=d.SystemUserId AND d.SystemUserId=e.SystemUserId AND "

                + "((b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate >= dateadd(day,27,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME()))) AND "
                + "b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate <= dateadd(day,33,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME())))) OR"

                + "(b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate >= dateadd(day,57,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME()))) AND "
                + "b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate <= dateadd(day,63,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME())))) OR "

                + "(b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate >= dateadd(day,87,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME()))) AND "
                + "b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate <= dateadd(day,93,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME())))) OR "

                + "(b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate >= dateadd(day,177,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME()))) AND "
                + "b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate <= dateadd(day,183,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME())))) OR "

                + "(b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate >= dateadd(day,-33,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME()))) AND "
                + "b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate <= dateadd(day,-27,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME())))) OR "

                + "(b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate >= dateadd(day,-63,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME()))) AND "
                + "b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate <= dateadd(day,-57,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME())))) OR "

                + "(b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate >= dateadd(day,-93,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME()))) AND "
                + "b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate <= dateadd(day,-87,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME())))) OR "

                + "(b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate >= dateadd(day,-3,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME()))) AND "
                + "b.new_SwWarrantyEndDate <= dateadd(day,3,(CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME()))))) "

                + "AND a.new_Support_RenewalContact=1 order by c.AccountId,a.new_Support_RenewalContact desc;";

        DataStore dataStore = new DataStore();
        result_set = stmt.executeQuery(terminated);

        while(result_set.next()){
            String newTagId,accountId,name,ownerId,newSoftwareWarrantyEndDate,jobTitle,firstName,lastName,
            emailAddress1,newSupportRenewalContact,newSupportedRenevalContact,yomiFullName,internalEmailAddress,newVPId,
            new_RVPId,newRenewalOpptyIdYr2,newRenewalOpptyIdYr3,newRenewalOpptyIdYr4,newRenewalOpptyIdYr5,levelOfSupport="";
            int remainingPeriod=0;

            newTagId=accountId=name=ownerId=newSoftwareWarrantyEndDate=jobTitle=firstName=lastName=emailAddress1=
                    newSupportRenewalContact=newSupportedRenevalContact=yomiFullName=internalEmailAddress=newVPId=new_RVPId=newRenewalOpptyIdYr2=
                    newRenewalOpptyIdYr3=newRenewalOpptyIdYr4=newRenewalOpptyIdYr5=levelOfSupport="";

            newTagId = result_set.getString("new_TagID");accountId = result_set.getString("AccountId");name = result_set.getString("Name");ownerId = result_set.getString("OwnerId");
            newSoftwareWarrantyEndDate = result_set.getString("new_SwWarrantyEndDate");jobTitle = result_set.getString("JobTitle");firstName = result_set.getString("FirstName");
            lastName = result_set.getString("LastName");emailAddress1 = result_set.getString("EMailAddress1");newSupportRenewalContact = result_set.getString("new_Support_RenewalContact");
            newSupportedRenevalContact = result_set.getString("new_SupportedRenevalContact");yomiFullName = result_set.getString("YomiFullName");internalEmailAddress = result_set.getString("InternalEMailAddress");
            newVPId = result_set.getString("new_VPId");new_RVPId = result_set.getString("new_RVPId");newRenewalOpptyIdYr2 = result_set.getString("new_RenewalOpptyIDyr2");
            newRenewalOpptyIdYr3 = result_set.getString("new_RenewalOpptyIDyr3");newRenewalOpptyIdYr4 = result_set.getString("new_RenewalOpptyIDyr4");
            newRenewalOpptyIdYr5 = result_set.getString("new_RenewalOpptyIDyr5");levelOfSupport = result_set.getString("LevelofSupport");
```

Comment: show us the block of code/method which you are fetching , I think this partial code is not that useful by itself only.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the query directly in MSSQL Studio?  If so--and if it returns the same result--try commenting-out the WHERE clause and see what happens.  Then add clauses back one at a time until you find the culprit.

If it is a grouping problem, indenting the clause groups would help you find the mistake, too.